# У кнопки (button) меняю цвет фона background color, цвет меняется, но при этом уменьшается высота кнопки

Tags: android, android-studio

```
b1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(color1));
```

Как сделать так, чтобы не уменьшалась высота кнопки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я воспользовался советом уважаемого **TimurVI**!
В одном месте помогло! 
Но в другом нет: у соседних кнопок поменялся фон не корректно... Потом поизучаю... )

Но некоторое решение (на быструю руку) я таки нашел. Работает все норм. )

> **h=bOtvet1.getHeight();**
>   bOtvet1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(color1));
>   bOtvet2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(color2));
>   bOtvet3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(color1));
>   bOtvet4.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(color2));
>   **bOtvet1.setHeight(h);**

P.S.
Кнопки находятся внутри LinearLayout'а. Высота у кнопок настроена как: **MATCH_PARENT**

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите установить Background и сохранить другие стили, можно попробовать вот так

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Или вот так попробуйте

```
b.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```